# Enterprise Wide Cluster Streaming System

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, confluent-platform, fault-tolerance

I'm interested in deploying an enterprise service bus on a fault tolerant system with a variety of use cases that include tracking network traffic and analyzing social media data. I'd prefer to use a streaming application, but open to the idea of micro-batching. The solution will need to be able to take imports and exports from a variety of sources (bus).

I have been researching various types of stream-processing software platforms here:

https://thenewstack.io/apache-streaming-projects-exploratory-guide/

But I've been struggling with the fact that many (all) of these projects are open source and I don't like the large implementation risk.

I have found Apache Kafka attractive because of the Confluent Platform built on-top, but I can't seem to find anything similar to Confluent out there and want to know if there are any direct competitors built on top of another Apache project. Or an entirely private solution.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Azure Event Hub, Google PubSub, and Amazon Kineses are the closest alternatives. Why do you need Apache? If so, Amazon ActiveMQ is the only one I know of

Comment: I should of mentioned that it's needs to be an on-prem solution not through a 3rd party service.

Comment: So how about Flink? Data artisans is a company behind that... Databricks for Spark. Streamsets also exists, and is the closest thing to Confluent I immediately know of other than Hortonworks and Cloudera